# Control name already in use error

Tags: winforms, custom-controls

I'm trying to figure out how to get the control to add a "1", "2", etc at the end of the name when I drag it from the toolbox.  Currently all it does is drag the control and leaving the name as the control name; what I want to happen is if I drag it from the toolbox to have something to the effect of "MyButton1"; and if I drag another, "MyButton2".

Below is the skinny I followed.

Any help is appreciated, also, if you see something that needs improvement, let me know that as well.

Oh if anyone has a sample they can refer me to that would be great.

Thanks

```
// Button Code
using CustomControls.Designers;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace CustomControls
{
   [Designer(typeof(MyButtonDesigner))]
    public partial class MyButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button
    {
        public MyButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    // removed blah blah code

    }
}

//designer code
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

namespace CustomControls.Designers
{
    class MyButtonDesigner : ControlDesigner
    {

        public override void Initialize(IComponent component)
        {
            base.Initialize(component);

            MyButton uc = component as MyButton;
            this.EnableDesignMode(uc, "MyButton");
        }
    }
}

//from form1 designer code
   private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
        this.MyButton = new CustomControls.MyButton();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // MyButton
        // 
        this.MyButton.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("MyButton.BackgroundImage")));
        this.MyButton.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
        this.MyButton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        this.MyButton.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.MyButton.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.MyButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(193, 58);
        this.MyButton.Name = "M3Button";
        this.MyButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.MyButton.TabIndex = 2;
        this.MyButton.Text = "MyButton";
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(632, 457);
        this.Controls.Add(this.MyButton);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion
    private CustomControls.MyButton MyButton;
```

Comment: Hmm, that's pretty hard to get wrong.  You'd have to make a mistake in the custom designer for the component.  We can't see it.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I forgot to override the InitializeNewComponent.  I found something to work with from: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91265/UserControl-Prompts-for-ControlName-after-Drop-in